# How to re-input an AJAX request on press back button in the browser?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a search that returns an AJAX(MVC AJAX Form) grid, and, in the grid there is a "details" button. When I press "back" I want to return the page with the returned results(that are loaded via AJAX after the page has open).

How can I do that? Using ASP.NET MVC AJAX or Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a [back button plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin) for jQuery.